# Mysql configuration diagnostics and optimalisation

Tags: mysql

We are running Magento on our dedicated server. I've run a perl script mysqloptimizer, to find out if we needed to make adjustments. These are the results. I'm not that into MYSQL configuration, could someone give me advice on how to optimize my configuration ? I have the feeling the current settings have not optimal settings.

```
 -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------

- [--] Up for: 2h 58m 40s (321K q [29.965 qps], 1K conn, TX: 405M, RX: 112M)
- [--] Reads / Writes: 63% / 37%
- [--] Total buffers: 2.1G global + 2.9M per thread (500 max threads)
- [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.5G (91% of installed RAM)
- [OK] Slow queries: 0% (2/321K)
- [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (6/500)
- [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/1.4M
- [OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.2% (251K cached / 2K reads)
- [OK] Query cache efficiency: 77.3% (210K cached / 272K selects)
- [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 46109
- [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 17K sorts)
- [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 44
- [OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 16% (5K on disk / 30K total)
- [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (6 created / 1K connections)
- [!!] Table cache hit rate: 1% (128 open / 6K opened)
- [OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/2K)
- [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (174K immediate / 174K locks)
- [OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 365.1M/2.0G

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------

General recommendations:

    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance

    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate

    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability

    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries

    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes

    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits


Variables to adjust:

  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***

  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***

    query_cache_size (> 64M)

    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with joins)

    table_cache (> 128)
```

and here current configuration variables

```
local-infile=0
max_allowed_packet=16M
query_cache_size=64M
join_buffer_size=256K
tmp_table_size=16M
max_heap_table_size=64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=500
thread_cache_size=16
wait_timeout=120
max_connections=500
table_cache=128
```

Comment: You got the recommendations, have you tried following them and retesting your workload?

Comment: Yes I did, should I keep increasing the values for query_cache_size, join_buffer_size and table_cache and ignore the "dangerously high usage" and "add more ram" ?

Comment: You max possible memory comes in part from the maximum number of connections. If you don't ever expect those to reach 500, lower the number. That will lower the max usage by some multiple of per-thread cache sizes and allow for larger values in other cases. Also, look at the temporary tables created - better indexing should help you there - usual queries should not resort to creating tmp tables on the disk (unless it's loads of data).